# difference between bundle and parcelable

Tags: java, android

So I've been studying about passing data between activities and I found out there are three ways:

1) direct from `Intent`

2) `Parcelable`

3) `Bundle`

What is the difference between `Parcelable` and `Bundle`? When should we use each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) is an interface to be implemented by some model class. If class implements `Parcelable` then instances of this class can be serialized and deserialized from a Parcel. `Parcelable` is an effective android analogue of java `Serializable` interface.

Example of implemeting `Parcelable`:

```
data class User(val id: Long, val email: String?) : Parcelable {

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readLong(),
            parcel.readString()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeLong(id)
        dest.writeString(email)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<User> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): User {
            return User(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<User?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Also in kotlin there is `@Parcelize` annotation which simplifies the process in most cases:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(val id: Long, val email: String?) : Parcelable
```

2. [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) is a container for named values of types standard for android (including `Parcelable`), which is used to pass data between activies, fragments and other android app entites.

   ```
   val user = User(1L, "email@email.email")
   val bundle = Bundle().apply {
       putLong("userId", user.id)
       putString("userEmail", user.email)
       putParcelable("user", user)
   }

   val userId = bundle.getLong("userId")
   val userEmail = bundle.getString("userEmail")
   val user1: User? = bundle.getParcelable("user")
   ```

Comment: So which is better to use? Is it ok to use Bundle everytime instead of Parcelable?

Comment: It is not correct to choose one of them, in common case you won't be able to use `Parcelable` without using `Bundle`. `Parcelable` should be used only if you need to pass instance of some custom data class, otherwise there is no need in it.

Answer (score 1):

A bundle is a special dictionary designed for passing data via intents. It can accept primitives, Strings, Parceables, and Serializables. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle

Parceable is android's implementation of the Java Serializable, but faster. However it requires some boilerplate code in order to function.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

Typically you use bundle when you need to pass a mapping of key-values via an intent. However in case your values are not primitives or Strings, you need to pass a Parceable object(or Serializable which is less efficient).